# Rearrange data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

there is a target vector

```
f=c(3,2,1,4)
```

and a two columns data frame (df)

```
2 4
1 2
7 8
9 10
```

I want to rearrange all rows in the order of the target f vector..

```
7 8
1 2
2 4
9 10
```

is there an easy way?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is:

```
f <- c(3,2,1,4)
df <- matrix(c(2, 1, 7, 9, 4, 2, 8, 10), nrow=4)
df[f, ]
```